# Display App Store Web Page Without Launching App Store

Tags: ios

In my iPad app, I'd like to display an iTunes app web page in my own UIWebView. But the following code always launches the App Store and leaves my app:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL urlWithString:@"https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/facebook/id284882215?mt=8"];
[self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:_URL]];
```

Is there a way to display this web page in my app without launching the App Store?

Comment: is your app the facebook app?

Comment: No. It's an in-house app. That was just a URL I grabbed as an example.

Comment: actually not... Apples IOS or xcode doesnt allow you to do that. Maybe cuz of the features of the appstore. But no I think theres no possible way. Did you have a look at the web?